# Railscast #174 (Pagination with AJAX) not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination

I'm following a Railscast to implement a pagination without page reload.
This code works well but there are some details to improve:

```
$(function() {
  $(".pagination a").click(function() {
    $.get(this.href, null, null, "script");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Code with improvements which doesn't work:

```
$(function() {
  $(".pagination a").live("click", function(){
    $.get(this.href, null, null, "script");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Any ideas what's bad with this "live" method?

Comment: Please open the developer tools and get the actual error from the console tab. That would help us guiding you in the right direction.

Comment: It says "$(...).live is not a function"

Comment: I saw one guy wrote a comment under that railscast to switch 'live' to 'on', but it doesn't seem to work too

Comment: Can you also tell me the version of jquery you are using as version 1.7+ "live" function has been deprecated. It is better to use "on". Below link has more information about both function http://api.jquery.com/live/ http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Yep, found the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "on" instead of "live" because "live" is depreciated as of 1.7 and removed as of 1.9.

```
$(function() {
  $(".parent").on("click", '.pagination a', function(){
    $.get(this.href, null, null, "script");
    return false;
  });
});
```